# Git merge folder by folder?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 branches "master" and "slave", both branches did alot of changes. While merging, some folder need to be overwrite, some need to solve conflicts and some can just merge normally. What I wish is merge them part by part, folder by folder.

Step 1:
Merging "master" to "slave", so I checkout branch "slave"...

```
git checkout slave
```

Step 2:
FolderA, FolderB, FolderC need to be overwrite with the folders in "master", so what I did is...

```
git checkout master FolderA
git checkout master FolderB
git checkout master FolderC
git commit -am "Overwrite with master"
git push origin slave
```

Step 3:
FolderD, FolderE, FolderF are folders that will have conflicts, I wish I could do merge them one by one. Then use git mergetool to solve conflicts, something like...

```
(git merge master FolderD)?
git mergetool
```

But that will give me a error "fatal: 'FolderD' does not point to a commit".

Step 4:
FolderG to FolderZ have changes that doesn't have conflicts, so just merge normally.

```
git merge master
```

The conflicts will be complicate and need times to solve, thats why I wish to do it one by one, how do I achieve step 3 and be able to proceed to step 4?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I would do it.  Give it a try and see if it does what you want.

```
git checkout slave
git merge master
git checkout --theirs FolderA FolderB FolderC
git add FolderA FolderB FolderC
```

Now you'll be in a state, given your example, where conflicts will be left in FolderD through FolderZ which you can resolve and `git add`.  This should give you what you are asking for.

The only direct problem I see is your statement that you would like to resolve the conflicts one folder at a time.  The problem here is that Git's first layer is the commit which can span multiple folders at once.

One nice thing about this approach is that Git's history is maintained, whereas your proposed approach would destroy the history as you would be making a new, non-merge, commit for FolderA through C.

Another approach you might want to explore is using `git filter-branch` to semi-automatically rewrite each commit in a branch.  This will give you the ability to selectively accept and reject changes from each commit, allowing you to programmatically filter FolderA through Z as you see fit.  Take a look at:

http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch

Comment: This will merge and then overwrite folders ABC, the reason I didn't do that is my folders ABC contain xls,jpg,zip,rar...type of files, these binary files are troublesome on git mergetool when they have conflicts. It is ok to lost history after merging, the after merge "slave" branch is for me to start a new project. Thanks, I will read about filter-branch.